# Conditional expression in for-loop doesn't act as expected

Tags: java, for-loop, expression, conditional-statements, palindrome

I can't seem to identify what is wrong with my code. After reading about the String class, I tried to print a palindrome backwards with a much shorter code, but I get nothing on the console except the execution of the newlines. 
And I think the problem might be from the conditional expression in the for statement because when I used "i <= l && i > -1" and debugged it with a System.print(i +" "), I got a list of numbers ranging from 17 to 0. So what could be wrong with the current expression, why can't I use "i < l && i > -1"? Is there something illegal about it because I intend to use numbers from 16 to 0 instead?

```
public class StephenWork
{
    private String objString ;
    private int index;

    private void makeString ( String objString)
    {
        this.objString = objString;
    }

    private char[] printBackwards ()
    {
        int length = objString.length();
        char [] backwards = new char [length];

        for (index = length ; index < length && index > -1 ; index-- )
        {
            backwards [index] = objString.charAt(index);
        }

        return backwards;   
    }

    public static void main (String ... args)
    {
        String palindrome = "tod saw I was dot";

        int l = palindrome.length();
        char [] backwards = new char [l];

        for ( int i = l; i < l && i > -1 ; i-- )
        {

            //System.out.println(i); //I was using this to debug the value of i
            backwards [i] = palindrome.charAt(i);
        }

        String printPalin = new String (backwards);
        System.out.println(printPalin);

        StephenWork example = new StephenWork ();
        example.makeString("I love Java");
        System.out.println( example.printBackwards());
    }
}
```

Comment: If `i = l` on the first iteration, it won't pass the condition check `i < l`.

Comment: for ( int i = l; i > -1 ; i-- )

Comment: `for (init; condition; increment) { body }` is equivalent to `init; while (condition) { body; increment; }` - if you translate your for-loops to that form, the problem should become clearer.

Comment: Damn! That totally escaped me. Thanks guys, now I can see where I went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Index is set to the same value as length, so the loop won't execute because the condition is initially false.

Answer (score 0):

You problem is in the first portion of your for loops:

```
for( index = length ; index < length ...
```

and

```
for( int i = l; i < l ...
```

are gonna cause problems for you.  If `index` is set to the value of `length`, it isn't less than length so `index < length` returns `false` and the for loop will be skipped entirely. Same with your `i` and `l` for loop.

instead you should initialize to `length - 1`:

```
 for (index = length - 1 ; index < length && index > -1; index-- )
     backwards [index] = objString.charAt(index);
```

Modify you other loop in the same manner:

```
 for ( int i = l - 1; i < l && i > -1 ; i-- )
     backwards [i] = palindrome.charAt(i);
```

Comment: Thanks. I get it now. It must suck to be a novice. I was so sure of myself. Can you put me on the right track please? I want i to run through  palindrome indexes.

Comment: starting from the last index downward.